# How do you add a record to a SQLite TDataSource used in a TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac

I'm trying to learn C++ Builder and SQLite Database access. I have a *DataModule* with a `TFDConnection`, `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink`, `TFDQuery`, and `TDataSource`.

I have the main form with a `TDBGrid` that uses the `TDataSource`.  All working okay up to this point.  However, I have a button to add a new record on the main form.  Clicking it pops up another form as a modal window where I can enter the data for each field (These fields are not linked to anything, they are normal `TEdit` type controls).  When `OK` is clicked the new record should be added.

Before having the `TDBGrid` and the `TDataSource` I used `TFDConnection->ExecSQL()` to insert the data, however after adding the `TDBGrid` and `TDataSource` it wouldn't work and said the database is locked.   I thought that maybe the `TDataSource` must be used since it would have the lock, so I tried using the `TDataSource->DataSet->AppendRecord()` but it's doing the same thing.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::EditNewEntryExecute(TObject *Sender)
{
    // update dialog with the current entry data
    UpdateEntryDialog(&EntryData);

    if (EntryForm->ShowModal() == mrOk) {
        // get the new data from the dialog
        GetEntryDialogData(&EntryData);
        SqLiteDataModule->AddEntry(&EntryData);
    }
}


bool __fastcall TSqLiteDataModule::AddEntry(const sEntryData *entrydata)
{
  // column 0 is auto increment field
  SqLiteDataModule->DataSource1->DataSet->AppendRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((0, entrydata->uIcon, entrydata->EntryName, entrydata->Notes)));
    /*  SqLiteDataModule->FDConnection ->ExecSQL("insert into Entries(Icon,EntryName,Notes) values (:Icon, :EntryName, :Notes)",
                                                 OPENARRAY(Variant, (entrydata->uIcon, entrydata->EntryName , entrydata->Notes)));
    */
    return true;
}
```

NOTE: Testing using IBLite instead of SQLite works so something different with SQLite which is what I want to use due to no potential limits that IBLite has.

So my question is, how do I add the record in this situation using SQLite?

Comment: Please provide your code in the form of a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. It's hard to tell you why your code isn't working without being able to see that code.

Comment: It may have something to do with SQLite - It's pretty basic, TDBGrid, TDataSource, TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink, TFDQuery, and TFDConnection.  The later two were created using the Data Explorer and dragging over the table.

Comment: I found some information that may apply, the database locked can occur when Using a table to write where the SELECT operation is already active.  Until Sqlite3_reset() or Sqlite3_finalize() are called the SELECT statement is not complete.  So maybe the firedac implementation doesn't do that?

Comment: The code you've posted does not do a SELECT. Is there more code that you've not included? If so, you've not provided a [mre].

Comment: Correct, it's part of the TFDQuery (table) that has the Select * from TableName (created automatically by drag / drop from Data Explorer).   This is all done with the built-in parts, it doesn't work with SQLite but works with IBLite.  The only thing I did is add the TDBGrid and the code above.  If I don't activate the TFDQuery then update can happen but of course the TDBGrid is empty.

Comment: I setup a brand new project for SQLite, and found the problem only occurs if you set the connection "Connected" to true in the RAD Studio, if you leave them unconnected, but then in the Constructor do an ->Open() for both the TFDConnection and TFDQuery, then it works.  Not sure what the difference is between IBLite and SQLite or connecting automatically vs manual, but that is the difference.

Comment: Yes, that would do it. IIRC, SQLite is a single-user DB, and I think (but am not sure) that IBLite will allow multiple users. The `Connected` property would open a connection to the DB from the IDE, which wouldn't be closed when you run your app. You can test this by closing the IDE and running your app via Explorer or a command prompt to see if the issue resolves itself. I hadn't considered setting `Connected` in the IDE and then not unsettting it when you'd read the fields list. Nice catch!

Comment: I think it would have - I've since rebuilt an entirely new project - took me about an hour what took a week learning things (but was able to copy over some stuff too), At one point I had tried that (run outside ide) but didn't work, but thinking more, that was using the sample SQLite database provided, it doesn't work, you can't connect to it even in the UI.  Having the program create a new DB, then I was able to start doing things...